# How to change the default index in Kibana-4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

There are 6 indices in my machine and when ever I run Kibana-4 it points to only one index all the time. But when I try to do the visualizations,I have the option to select any of the indices. How do I change the default index to the one I frequently use?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go to the "settings" tab (indicated by red box 1).
Then to the "indices" tab (red box 2) and then select the index you want to set as default.
Here I have the intention of keeping the index named "restaurants" (red box 3) as the default index and have selected it. 
Then press the star button (red box 4) which is toward the right side. After pressing the "star " icon,you have the selected index as your default index.Also the star appears on the left side of the index name,and thus we know it has been selected as the default index.