# Hw to change default index to my index in kibana.index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to change the default index to my index in Kibana. I need to change this, i.e kibana.index. But I don't know how to find this ? I'm using Elasticsearch 6.4.3 and kibana:6.4.3. Please any one knows this? Thank you

I guess I need to change kibana.yml.Because I need to see only my index in Kibana. Also I've read this, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

My question is how to find this file to set the default index as my index?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default index in Kibana-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364900/how-to-change-the-default-index-in-kibana-4)

Comment: Sorry, No. I need to change kibana.yml. I need to see only my index in Kibana

Comment: I followed this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html. Pls go down and see  kibana.index: My question is how to find this?

Comment: You want to know where is yml file?

Comment: I found it in Kibana folder, and I saw this : # Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana . How to change this to my index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Opened my kibana.yml
I found this line in the file

```
# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"
```

If you have that present in your .yml file then simply uncomment it else add this line to your kibana.yml file

```
kibana.index: "my_index_name"
```